# Google Map work when app signed apk install in device but not work play store apk

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I trying to integrate google map to my app. Google map work perfectly in debug version apk. Also I am generate signed apk and install in device. The Google map works fine in signed apk version. But when I am install my app from Play store - The google map not load show white blank (SHA-1 key add in API Console and enable google map sdk for android). I am using -
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'`

Is anything I need to upgrade ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Published App on Play Store can't communicate with Google Maps API and Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671778/published-app-on-play-store-cant-communicate-with-google-maps-api-and-facebook)

Comment: I am not using facebook Api in my app.

Comment: I believe answer explains what is happening to Google Maps API as well. Or read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976365/google-maps-doesnt-show-after-upload-to-google-play

Comment: @xomena thank's for your reply. Your given link solution not work for me. I find my way to solve it. Can you please remove duplicate mark in this question.

Comment: Removed my flag, but still surprised how unrestricted key might solve the problem.

Comment: I am also confused, but apps works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem to use **Browser key (Auto Create by google service)** key. I don't how it's works but it solve my problem. Now google map load in play store apk version.

[image]